Use values in files in helm charts
Does it even possible to inline values in files folder?
Introduction
I have simple chart with such file structure:
./Chart.yaml
./values.yaml
./templates/configMap.yaml
./files/app.yml

File files/app.yml:
some:
  value: {{ .Values.someValue }}

File values.yaml:
someValue: 42

And configMap.yaml like that:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
  namespace: my
data:
data:
  {{- $root := . }} 
  {{- range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "files/*" }} 
  {{ base $path }}: {{ $root.Files.Get $path | quote }} 
  {{- end }}

Problem
After helm install i will get such config:
some:
  value: {{ .Values.someValue }}

instead of
some:
  value: 42

Question
Does it even possible to get this one? Does it possible to inline values in non templates file? Does tpl function help?
some:
  value: 42


I've heard some people complaining about file extensions when using Helm. What happens if you rename files/app.yml to files/app.yaml?

@RuiJarimba thank you for your idea but it didn't help.

Do I understand you correctly that your problem is that the file located at ./files/app.yml is not being processed by Helm's templating mechanism? If so, Helm's documentation says that only files within the templates/ directory will be processed. Hence, you could move your app.yml to the templates/ directory if that is a feasible option in your case.

@MartinH. yes, partially. I have a file in files/ and it is useful (by some reasons) to place it there over placing it in templates folder. I've solved the problem by copying the file programmatically before running any helm command. Hack. Dirty hack but it works.
